# "Invalid use of group function" with no group function used

Tags: mysql, sql

Anyone has an idea why I get this error message:

> Lookup Error - MySQL Database Error: Invalid use of group function

for the following query?

```
select * from users u where u.CreationDate BETWEEN min(u.CreationDate) AND 
DATE_ADD(min(u.CreationDate), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

I have to group function in the query!

Comment: its due to min function "min(u.CreationDate)"

Comment: Your query makes no sense. What should it do?

Comment: "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference"

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use aggregation functions in the `where` clause.  What you want is a `join` and aggregation to get the minimum date:

```
select *
from users u cross join
     (select min(CreationDate) as mincd
      from users
     ) uu
where u.CreationDate BETWEEN uu.mincd AND DATE_ADD(uu.mincd, INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use MIN inside a BETWEEN clause, but you can:

```
select * from users u where u.CreationDate 
BETWEEN (SELECT min(u.CreationDate) FROM users) AND 
DATE_ADD((SELECT min(u.CreationDate) FROM users), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

If this is a procedure, you can store the minimum date in a variable and then use it i the query instead of the redundant call.